# How to pass a vault(vault-variable) to multiple roles where the roles themselves have multiple dependent-roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-vault

I'm running ansible 2.7.10 and have a playbook where I "include" different roles in different plays.
All the roles I call have common dependent roles.

I'm at a stage now where I want all the roles within that playbook to read a vault.

This works if I pass the file as an extra variable ( -e @ )

```
- name: main playbook - play 1
  hosts: hosts1
  vars_files:
  - "<path_to_universal_vault>"
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: role1

- name: main playbook - play 2
  hosts: hosts2
  vars_files:
  - "<path_to_universal_vault>"
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: role2
```

Both role1 and role2 have dependent roles:

```
- role: role_a
- role: role_b
- role: role_c
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798445) that I can include the vault in the "vars" for the main role.
Is there a way for the dependent-roles to inherit variables(vault, in this case) from the main role?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we should start by creating a `./vault/main.yml`, from your project root, and adding there the secret:

```
my_vault_secret: "It works!"
```

Then, **option A**, to include vault vars with the main role, that would be allocated on playbook runtime, create `./roles/role1/default/main.yml` and add your variable which will reference the secret:

```
my_vault_var: "{{ my_vault_secret }}"
```

Then use `my_vault_var` in `role_a`, `role_b`, `role_c`.

Or, **option B**, keep the `./vault/main.yml` with all your secrets, including the ones used in `role_a`, `role_b`, `role_c`, but instead of using a default/main.yml, include the vault file directly in the playbook you are using to execute the tasks in `role1` and `role2`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - "vault/main.yml"

  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
```

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [role_a : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "It works!"
}
```

Project structure would look like this, with `defaults` necessary only for Option A:

```
my_ansible_repo
|-- group_vars
    |-- main.yml
|-- vault
    |-- main.yml
|-- roles
    |-- role1
        |-- defaults
            |-- main.yml
        |-- tasks
            |-- main.yml
        |-- meta  
            |-- main.yml
    |-- role_a
        |-- tasks
            |-- main.yml
|-- my_playbook.yml
```

More about Ansible default variables in the official documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-default-variables), and about using variable files with playbooks, [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files).

Comment: Adding to the comment above as I couldn't edit it(sorry, I am new!):
I was hoping to avoid adding the vault to every role I use and have it defined universally instead.
I am using the "newer syntax" for using roles as per the ansible documentation. Hence, the "include_role". Wonder if it really make a difference though.

Comment: @shackledmystic in both situations I've described, you should have only a single vault file, that is located in a ./vault/ directory, and not inside of individual roles directories. I've updated my answer to make it more clear.